# How to add a APN policy into Android Applications in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, apn

I'm a beginner to Android developments. I want to support from an Android expert for this problem. I need to Create android APN controller mobile application by using Android Studio. This is an assignment in my university. But I have no idea about how to do this task. But they provide me several links of the android documentation. I read them but I cannot take any Idea about it. So what sould I do for that?

Is there any android expert, can give me support for that?